# How to write multiple columns in spark dataframe to kafka queue

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-kafka

I know that we can integrate spark with kafka and write the dataframe in format of key and value to kafka queue as shown below

df - dataframe

```
 df.withColumnRenamed("Column_1", "key")
 .withColumnRenamed("Column_2", "value")
 .write()
 .format("kafka")
 .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
 .save()
```

But how do I write column 3,4,5 and many to kafka queue? 
How can I write the entire row to kafka queue in a single go?

Any suggestions are appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Kafka only gets (key, value) formed messages. So you have to aggregate columns to one value (like JSON). here is example

This should work: (Construct the appropriate `value_fields`)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val value_fields = df.columns.filter(_ != "Column_1") 

df
.withColumnRenamed("Column_1", "key")
.withColumn("value", to_json(struct(value_fields.map(col(_)):_*)))
.select("key", "value")
.write()
.format("kafka")
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
.save()
```

Comment: can you please be more java specific